# Access device with XRDP from an outside connection or network

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, raspberrypi, xrdp

I have set up xrdp on an Ubuntu 20.04 image on a Raspberry PI. It works great when I join from a computer that shares the same network.

But how may I access it from another network/outside connection?

Comment: This is a classic basic networking question that is OS-independent. Everything on your local network shares the same public IP address -- your router's public IP address. (That's what a router does: It enables sharing). Look up how to do *port forwarding* on your router. And perhaps a decent primer on Port Forwarding in general; lots out there just a Search Engine away.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't even knew how the procedure was named. What I was searching led me nowhere new, obviously, I wasn't using the right keywords. Will attempt those and see. Thanks.

Comment: No apologies needed. You don't know until you ask.

Answer (score 0):

as others mentioned, you should look up about port forwarding. Another thing that you might need is a STATIC IP, which you can get where I got mine: dyndns.org

I access my ubuntu on XRDP all the times from outside my network